# Tenses in subordinate clauses

Tags: present-perfect, present-simple, subordinate-clauses

In most subordinate clauses we can't use "will" to refer to the future. This is usually true after conjuntions of time, question words, if, whether and in defining relative clauses.

However, in these cases, we can use present simple or present perfect instead. I wonder if there is any difference between them. For example:

> We'll have a party when we **take** our exams.

VS

> We'll have a party when **we've taken** our exams.

I'm not talking about tenses after hope, bet, as, than, because, although, since and cases where the use of "will" in subordinate clauses is necessary.

Comment: Hi! Yes, the difference is the difference between simple and perfect. Please edit to show that you've looked up a little bit about these tenses and what you already understand.

Comment: @AndyBonner The present simple normally refers to a generally repeated action or an ongoing state, and present perfect normally refers to a past event. But in these time clauses, they refer to *one-time future* events, so knowledge of those functions alone wouldn't help the OP understand the meaning here. THAT SAID, there is a lack of information about what the OP already knows about time clauses with "when".

Comment: Kaymond, Are you asking about those tenses in *all subordinate clauses*, or just in *subordinate clauses of time*, or just in *subordinate clauses of time with "when"*? And as Andy said, before we can answer this, we need to know what you already understand about the topic (whichever topic it is), and exactly what part of it you're unsure about. So I'm closing this question (for now) to new answers. Please [edit] this information into your question, and then put "@gotube" in a comment so I can reopen the question. Thanks!

Comment: @gotube added more information!

Comment: It isn't true that "will" can't be used in defining (also called "restrictive") relative clauses. "The person *who will administer the exams*," "Students *that will be present in class*," and "The day *which will be selected*" are all examples of defining relative clauses using "will" for the future tense.

Comment: @Kyamond Great work! More of that kind of question please!

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that with *present simple* the clause refers to the time **when the event starts**, but with the *present perfect* version, it refers to the time **when the event is finished**.

So your sentence with *present simple* means *we will have a party **while taking our exams***, and with *present perfect* means *we will have a party **once our exams are over***.

The intended meaning is probably the second one, but the first sounds like fun too.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask whether you have any sources for your answer?

Comment: @Kyamond Other than being a native speaker and being 100% confident, no, I don't have any sources to back this up. Here's one place that agrees with me, but they're not authoritative: https://test-english.com/explanation/b1-2/when-i-do-vs-when-i-have-done/